# Forming Roman Empire as unreformed pagan

Tags: crusader-kings-2

If I'm unreformed pagan and control all the key duchies, can I convert to christianity via concubine, form the Roman Empire, and immediately convert back to my capital's religion? Will I still keep the Augustus trait?

Comment: Jeebus I am more interested in knowing how did you manage to do that :O With the excruciating gavelkind succ law and limits in levies & taxes, I salute you, Augustus!

Comment: Actually I got around all 3 of those by somewhat abusing the mechanics. For gavelkind, simply do not have kids; either go seduction focus and legitimize a single bastard once he's an adult with good stats or elect your relatives. For levies, just never stop being at war; if you're playing as tribal that means you get to keep the 2500 unit army for 500 prestige until it dies. Lastly, for taxes, whenever you take over new territory, transfer every baron level vassal to a theocratic count, that way your tribal vassals have no baron vassals under them and you still get tax from the priest.

Comment: That seduction technique is brilliant (Though I have to be careful to make sure that mother is at my court at time of birth so I make a courtier marry her or simply stick to my own court's women). Already formed Scandinavia ^_^

Comment: Once you get an empire title you can stop doing it , since if you don't create/usurp a 2nd empire title, you will only have 1 empire title so all the non-primary heirs will still be your vassals (but you will lose kingdom titles which I personally dislike to do). This works because gavelkind automaticaly creates kingdom titles when able, but it doesn't create empire titles when able. You will lose out on a lot of possible prestige gain though.

Answer (score 2):

You can have a norse Roman Empire, however you can't change back immediately. This shouldn't figure too big a problem though.

A detailed step-by-step guide of what I did:

1. I took the Byzantine Empire by kidnapping a close relative of the Baselius and got a kid with her (kinky!)
2. Conquered the required Duchies
3. Moved my Capital to a Christian County to convert
4. Gave my heir the title of Fylkyr (the religious head of reformed norse)
5. Switched to Christian
6. Formed Rome
7. 'Lost' to a Tyranny rebellion so my (still norse) heir takes over. (you could also just wait for your current ruler to die, but that might take a while)

Whether you keep the title of Augustus I can't explicitely remember, but I don't see why not. I will load up the safe when getting home to check.

Note: I do not know whether any DLCs are required for this as I always play with all enabled, and it was well over 2 years that I did this myself, so they might have changed it (which I doubt however)

EDIT: The DLCs needed for this: Legacy of Rome to form Rome (obviously), Old Gods to play as Pagan (thanks to @RossRidge for pointing this out) and Sons of Abraham so you can move your capital.